# Automated test execution slower with Selenium grid

Tags: automation, grid, protractor, selenium-grid

At our company we have setup a test infrastructure consisting of a Selenium Hub server (located ). There are 5-7 selenium nodes that register with the hub during test execution. What we noticed is that for individual tests, the test execution time is at least 30-40 % slower compared to a local execution. I have checked the network traffic, and it doesn't seem to be the problem (ping is less than 1 ms between hub and nodes). The hub is not running out of resources either.

From your experience with Selenium Grid, have you noticed such differences? Is this normal (I suppose to some extent this is ok, but still). What do you think? And what else could we try to see where the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I extremely recommended to use [Selenoid](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/) for this purpose. Currently, it is the best tool for running in parallel e2e tests.